# How to make one function work if checked and another work if not checked with checkbox

Tags: jquery, html

So I'm literally frustrated out of my mind, I've been trying to fix this for about 30 mins but still failing.

I want the `keyup()` function to be active when the checkbox is ticked, else I want the `click()` function to be active when the checkbox is not ticked. But I got it to work somewhat close, when I check, it works but when I uncheck it still uses keyup and click...

if anyone could help me I'd appreciate it!

My code:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="saut" onchange="isChecked()">
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function isChecked() {
  var checked = $('input#saut').is(':checked');
  if (checked == true) {
    $('button#searchbutton').attr("disabled", true);
    $('input#searchquery').keyup(function () {
      alert("omfg keyup!");
      return;
    });
  } else {
    $('button#searchbutton').attr("disabled", false);
    $('button#searchbutton').click(function () {
      alert("omfg button!!");
      return;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply move the check inside the event handlers ?

Comment: `if(checked == true)` What are you trying/misunderstanding here?

Comment: @dystroy What do you mean mate?

Comment: `.click` and `.keyup` bind events to those objects until you unbind them. Easiest way would be to do the check inside the handlers instead of outside of them though you could mess about unbinding and binding events if you really wanted.

Comment: @bondye I am trying to make a search bar, and I'd like to make it use the keyup() or click(), so if the user checks the box, it will search as the user types, but if it's not ticked, it will only search after they submit the search.

Comment: @jimjimmy1995 - How would I do that ?

Comment: @DhameshMakwana I've made an answer to explain it, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this :

```
$('#saut').change(function(){ // let's enable/disable the button on (un)check
    $('#searchbutton').prop("disabled", this.checked);
});
$('#searchquery').keyup(function () {
    if (!$('#saut').is(':checked')) return; // do nothing if not checked
    alert("omfg keyup!");
});
$('#searchbutton').click(function () {
    if ($('#saut').is(':checked')) return; // do nothing if checked
    alert("omfg button!!");
});
```

Note also that I used [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `attr` and that I cleaned the selectors (when you select by ID, don't put anything else than the ID in the selector).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just bind those both event and check for checkbox later

```
 $('input#searchquery').keyup(function () {
     if($("#saut").is(":checked")){
          alert("omfg keyup!");
     }
 });

 $('button#searchbutton').click(function () {
     if(!$("#saut").is(":checked")){
         alert("omfg button!!");
     }
 });
```

You can also bind event then unbind it or use jquery `one`

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing in your code is to *register* an event listener; not to fire that actual code. There is nothing in your code that unregisters the listener when they are no longer to be active. While you could do that, it would probably be neater still to just bind the listener once, and add the check in the handler:

```
function searchKeyup() {
    if(!$('#saut').is(':checked')) { return; }
    // keyup code
}

function searchClick() {
    if($('#saut').is(':checked')) { return; }
    // click code
}

$(function() {
    $('#searchquery').keyup(searchKeyup);
    $('#searchbutton').click(searchClick);
});
```

Since you're also disabling and enabling the button, you might also do something like this:

```
$('#saut').change(function() {
   var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
   $('#searchbutton').prop('disabled', checked);
   $('#searchquery').toggleClass('disabled', !checked);
});

$(document).on('click', '#searchbutton:not(:disabled)', function() {
   // button click
});

$(document).on('click', '#searchquery:not(.disabled)', function() {
   // keyup
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Try to stay away from using inline jQuery function calls. It creates a whole world of problems you don't want to deal with. It's much better to keep your scripts out of the DOM.

http://jsfiddle.net/talymo/hreZH/

```
function isChecked() {
     var checked = $('input#saut').is(':checked');
     console.log(checked);
     if (checked == true) {
         $('button#searchbutton').attr("disabled", true);
         $('input#searchquery').keyup(function () {
             alert("omfg keyup!");
             return;
         });
     } else {
         $('button#searchbutton').attr("disabled", false);
         $('button#searchbutton').click(function () {
             alert("omfg button!!");
             return;
         });
     }
}

$('input').on('click', function(){
    isChecked();
});
```

Also, it doesn't appear as if you had your search form in your code, so I went ahead and added it in there, got it working great for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use exactly this mechanism, you should unsubscribe unnecessary events. So your code should be:

```
function isChecked() {
 var checked = $('input#saut').is(':checked');

 if (checked == true) {
     $('button#searchbutton').attr("disabled", true);
     $('input#searchquery').on("keyup", function () {
         alert("omfg keyup!");
         return;
     });
     $('button#searchbutton').off("click");
 } else {
     $('button#searchbutton').attr("disabled", false);
     $('button#searchbutton').on("click", function () {
         alert("omfg button!!");
         return;
     });
     $('input#searchquery').off("keyup");
 }
```

So use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind events and [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to unbind.
Or as [dystroy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263525/dystroy) wrote you may simply add the check into handlers.